# How to add at a main layout an imageView controlled from another thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, imageview

I'm making an app for Android. I have reached my goal with the single main thread pushing a button!!! (show an image saved on the SD in an ImageView) But I need to do it with threading to save some time and because I will make other threads.

The problem when I do this on a new thread a warning appears that tells me:

> "Only the original thread that created a view hierachy can touch its
>   views."

And the Image is not opened.

Here is this code:

```
public class intsocketclient extends Activity implements  OnClickListener{
    public ImageView imagen;
        private Button connectPhones;              
        private Handler conectarhandler = null;
    private Runnable conectarunner = null;
public boolean condicion = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);    
            imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
            connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
            connectPhones.setOnClickListener(this);

            conectarhandler = new Handler();        
            conectarunner = new Runnable() { 
                public void run() {
                conectayenvia(); 
            conectarhandler.post(this);          

                }
          };                  
        }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
     if(v==connectPhones) {              
         new Thread (conectarunner).start();                 
     }
}

public void conectayenvia () {
    if (condicion){              
                  condicion = false;
                  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/recibido.jpg");
                  imagen.setImageBitmap(bMap);                                      
     }  
    }   
}
```

But I really need it to be this way.

Is it possible to take the main layout (the original "main.xml") and some kind of "add" over it another main file (a "threadmain.xml" which only contains the imageView)but also with the capability of pushing buttons and other kind of things of the first original "main.xml" layout????????

Answer (score 2):

use AsyncTask, as it will handle threads automatically, the preExecute and postExecute methods of AsyncTask run on UI thread.

```
  private class DF extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
         private Bitmap bMap;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    if (condicion){              
              condicion = false;
              bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/recibido.jpg");

                     }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              imagen.setImageBitmap(bMap);                                      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

call the asyncTask in onClick.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
     if(v==connectPhones) {              
             new DF().execute();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to run UI methods not on the UI thread. The solution is to call [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) from the other thread.